# Azure Function v1 - Unable to get POST body content with PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function v1 (PowerShell) where runtime set is 64bit.

My Azure Function should execute some operations on my SharePoint site using PnP.

I've uploaded DLLs on `modules` folder and they are correctly loaded when function is started. Then I try to call my function sending this JSON as body in my POST call:

```
{
"name":"Test1"
}
```

My function (I've removed all SharePoint PnP commands) is this one:

```
using namespace System.Net
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
$requestBody = Get-Content $Request -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name
Write-Host $name
```

Every time I run the function I receive an error 500 with this output:

```
{
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
  "requestId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "statusCode": 500,
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Exception while executing function: Functions.MyFunction-> PowerShell script error -> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null."
}
```

I think that it could be refer to `Get-Content $Request` but I don't know how can I fix this code to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure Functions v1 (as per your title), that is the reason. Powershell is supported on v2 or higher:

[image]

Comment: That's a good point. Is it possible to use modules with Azure Function v2? I've tried with v3 but it seems that DLLs in modules folder are not loaded.

Comment: Yes, make sure they are enabled in your host.json 

{
  "version": "2.0",
  "managedDependency": {
    "Enabled": true
  }

Comment: Then add the modules to requirements.ps1 

@{
    Az = '2.*'
    dbatools = "1.*"
}